# setEnterTransition only shows Fade

Tags: java, android, activity-transition

I wrote an application with multiple activities in it.

I would like to add a transition in between (Slide).

I wrote the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getWindow().requestFeature( Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS );
        getWindow().setEnterTransition( new Slide() );

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_profile );
        ....
```

And then when I click a button to open another activity I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( DiscoverActivity.this, UploadActivity.class );
                    startActivity( intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation( this ).toBundle() );
```

However, no matter if I changed to `Explore()` or `Fade()` or `Slide()` it seems like it keeps showing me Fade.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `setEnterTransition` in the Activity You are opening not in the current `Activity` that's what the name suggest its a transition which will apply during entering in the `Activity`.

Move the below code to  `UploadActivity`. Also you can change the `Gravity` of `Slide` by passing it Gravity by default its `Gravity.BOTTOM`.

```
getWindow().requestFeature( Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS );
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.END));
```